# Visualize RDF in Cytoscape.js?

Tags: rdf, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I visualize an RDF graph using a convoluted process of SPARQL query -> CSV export -> import into Cytoscape Desktop -> export as JSON -> import into Cytoscape.js. Is there some way of directly visualizing RDF graphs in Cytoscape.js, for example with a plugin similar to RDFScape for Cytoscape Desktop?

P.S.: For anyone else having that problem, you can use our solution like this: http://www.snik.eu/graph/?sparql=https://dbpedia.org/sparql&graph=http://dbpedia.org. With the "&instances" parameter you can load instances as well (won't work for DBpedia because it is too large). The source code is at .http://github.com/imise/cytoscape-js.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a small module using Node.js.  Load your data from your database (probably using a module [from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search)), and then convert your data into the Cytoscape.js [JSON format](http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json) in your Node.js module.  (You can even load that data directly into Cytoscape.js on Node.js headlessly if you want.)

This should automate the conversion process.